# insert php array into mysql from csv

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, insert

I'm triying to import a CSV file into MySQL.

My CSV is in rows: `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, `id4`,..., `user1`, `user2`, `user3`,...

I need to make a pair of numbers `(id1,user1)` and insert them into MySQL.

I have this code but in time to insert it returns `error 1064`.

```
<?php
 $arr = file('file.csv');

 $linea = substr($arr[0], 0, strlen(trim($arr[0])) - 1);
 $id = explode(',', $linea);

 $linea = substr($arr[1], 0, strlen(trim($arr[1])) - 1);
 $pe = explode(',', $linea);


 foreach ($id as $key => $value)
 {
   $val[] = '(' . $id[$key] . ',' . $pe[$key] . ')';
 $linea = implode(',', $val);

  }

 $sqlr = 'INSERT INTO $db.datos (`cod_art`, `pes`) values  '. $linea .'   ' ;

 $resultado = mysql_query($sqlr) or die ('Failed to execute ' . $sqlr . ' due to ' . mysql_errno());  
?>
```

Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: Error 1064 is mysql syntax error so print your query and check it.probably you are passing single value but have specified two coloumns

Comment: echo $sqlr to see how's your data formatted inside the sql so we can see what's wrong

Comment: So the CSV input goes row->user->row->user etc? Could it not be 2 columns row-user (newline) row-user? This would make things a lot easier

Comment: Hello, thank you for the ansewers. I print $sqlr and the result is (16,3.10),(60,1.30),(18,5.00),(7,3.40),(46,5.00),(66,0.50),(37,7.40). This is that I want. But the insert is wrong.  The csv file format is first row id1, id2, id3,  second row user1, user2, user3,      Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
     $filename_csv = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($filename_csv);
    if($extension=="csv")
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");

        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

        $sql = mysql_query("insert into upload_data(spent,click,filename,date) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo $error1=ucwords('<div style="margin-left:60px;position: absolute;width: 400px; color: #006400;">CSV File has been successfully Imported</div>');

        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo $error1=ucwords('<div style="margin-left:60px;position: absolute;width: 400px; color: #CC0000;">Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File</div>');
       // echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
        }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.  I have the error "Invalid..." I change "file" for "promar". I have to change something more? Thank you